# SetBox set to checked after click on textview - ExpandableListView

Tags: android, checkbox, hashmap, expandablelistview

I am trying to create the following with my layout:

1) After a click on a `TextView` I want to set the `CheckBox` to checked state.

2) After start a new session set these check boxes into last state (`SharedPreferences`). Right now I am using `HashMap` for keeping state of the check boxes (I have that from some ExpandableListView tutorial).

Has someone solved this problem and can help me achieve this?

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: i solved the first problem, but i have no idea how to solve the second, anyone?

Comment: It´s basically [this](https://github.com/bhat-dinesh/ExpandableListViewWithCheckBox) with some changes for my purpose. But these changes have no effect on working...